# Passing variables, creating instances, self, The mechanics and usage of classes: need explanation

Tags: python, class, call, parameter-passing, instance-variables

I just rewrote a working program into functions in a class and everything messed up.

**First**, in the `__init__` section of the class I declared a bunch of variables with `self.variable=something`.

Should I be able to access/modify these variables in every function of the class by using `self.variable` in that function? In other words, by declaring `self.variable` I have made these variables, global variables in the scope of the class right?

If not, how do I handle self?

**Second**, how do I correctly pass arguments to the class?

**Third**, how do I call a function of the class outside of the class scope?

**Fouth**, how do I create an Instance of the `class INITIALCLASS` in another `class OTHERCLASS`, passing variables from `OTHERCLASS` to `INITIALCLASS`?

I want to call a function from `OTHERCLASS` with arguments from `INITIALCLASS`. What I've done so far is.

```
class OTHERCLASS():
    def __init__(self,variable1,variable2,variable3):
        self.variable1=variable1
        self.variable2=variable2
        self.variable3=variable3
    def someotherfunction(self):
        something=somecode(using self.variable3)
        self.variable2.append(something)
        print self.variable2
    def somemorefunctions(self):
        self.variable2.append(variable1)
        
class INITIALCLASS():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1=value1
        self.variable2=[]
        self.variable3=''
        self.DoIt=OTHERCLASS(variable1,variable2,variable3)

    def somefunction(self):
        variable3=Somecode
        #tried this
        self.DoIt.someotherfunctions()
        #and this
        DoIt.someotherfunctions()
```

I clearly didn't understand how to pass variables to classes or how to handle `self`, when to use it and when not. I probably also didn't understand how to properly create an instance of a class. In general I didn't understand the mechanics of classes so please help me and explain it to me like I have no idea (which I don't, it seems). Or point me to a thorough video, or readable tutorial.

All I find on the web is super simple examples, that didn't help me much. Or just very short definitions of classes and class methods instances etc.

I can send you my original code if you guys want, but its quite long.

Comment: Read the Python tutorial [section on classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Please learn about the formatting options here, especially for code.

Comment: I don't mean to be patronizing, but the meta-answer here is that you need to slow down a bit and figure out exactly where your code is deviating from your expectations. Try to make small changes from your working code and test each change until something breaks. Refactoring, they call it. Also, don't beat yourself up, it's just code--it never makes sense until it does.

Comment: TO ->BrenBarn i had already read it, and its what i mean it gives the very basics, but I dont understand how to use it in more complex environements, because i probably didnt understand the explenation in depth. This tutorial didnt really help me. what mgilson posted it closer to making me understand, but igeuss also more tedious to write. But thanks!
@Marcin I have asked several times in my older posts, how to do stuff concerning formatting, but havent got an answer. What exactly did  I do wrong?

Comment: @Ben yes your right of course, I did make considerable changes to my code, without the checking steps, but it was all working before and i basically just repacked it into functions and classes, to make it more structured and easier to tweak/extend, basically i cant properly instance methods and pass arguments to the class the variables arent defined or the objects dont have the attributes. I just dont have aclear picture how to pass variables around or call methods and what arguments to add where.

Comment: Baf - look at your post. Notice that there is code which is not code-formatted, but interpreted as marked-up. Edit your post, and select the code fragments, then hit the `{}` button - it will be formatted, and then you can observe the syntax.

Comment: @Marcin Thx! looks better now! Ill keep that in mind.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
class Foo          (object):
    # ^class name  #^ inherits from object

    bar = "Bar" #Class attribute.

    def __init__(self):
        #        #^ The first variable is the class instance in methods.  
        #        #  This is called "self" by convention, but could be any name you want.
        #^ double underscore (dunder) methods are usually special.  This one 
        #  gets called immediately after a new instance is created.

        self.variable = "Foo" #instance attribute.
        print self.variable, self.bar  #<---self.bar references class attribute
        self.bar = " Bar is now Baz"   #<---self.bar is now an instance attribute
        print self.variable, self.bar  

    def method(self, arg1, arg2):
        #This method has arguments.  You would call it like this:  instance.method(1, 2)
        print "in method (args):", arg1, arg2
        print "in method (attributes):", self.variable, self.bar


a = Foo() # this calls __init__ (indirectly), output:
                 # Foo bar
                 # Foo  Bar is now Baz
print a.variable # Foo
a.variable = "bar"
a.method(1, 2) # output:
               # in method (args): 1 2
               # in method (attributes): bar  Bar is now Baz
Foo.method(a, 1, 2) #<--- Same as a.method(1, 2).  This makes it a little more explicit what the argument "self" actually is.

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self.Foo = Foo()

b = Bar(a)
b.arg.variable = "something"
print a.variable # something
print b.Foo.variable # Foo
```

Comment: Hey mgilson,
Thx for the reply and the effort u put into your post. What exactly is the difference between the class atribute bar and the instance attribute self.bar? except that self.bar gets called imidiatly  because its in the __init__ method? I mean what can i do with self.bar that i cant do with bar? Also why do you pass that arguments to a.method directly? couldnt you pass them to Foo() when th instance is created and use them through Foo()? And if yes How? How would you go about  if the instance is created in another class, were Foo() isnt defined? or is it always defined.

Comment: If an instance doesn't have a particular instance attribute, then it falls back on the class attribute and uses that.  So, this is one way for every instance of a class to share a piece of data.  Does that make sense? (I added a few comments in `__init__`).  Does that help?  As for your other questions, the arguments passed to `Foo()` get forwarded on to `__init__`.  If it helps, instance methods are just like functions except that their first argument is the instance used to call that method.

Comment: When i tried to creat an instance of myclass in otherclass the Name didnt change colour, shouldnt every classname be colured? lets say i have a variable thats defined in myclass through self.variable in __init__ ,how can i go about to use it throughout the class methods? can I create an instance of otherclass in myclass passing the variables to otherclass where they are attributed to self.othervariable and the can be used throughout otherclass and its methods not haveing to pass them to an instance method in my class?

Comment: It didn't change color?  what does that mean?  You mean syntax highlighting?  That's completely dependent on your editor...

Comment: @Baf I've extended the example a tiny amount.  Does that help?

Comment: Oh and btw, youve answered to me in an older post, thanks for the support!

Comment: hmm idont see any change? maybe I already opened the edited version in the first place. What did you change? maybe i should refresh.
Yes i meant syntax highlighting, Im using Notepad++, i just said that because in every example ive seen up till now Class names were highlighted.

Comment: Now i see the change. Let me have a look. THX

Comment: Very good, gonna try to emulate it with my code tomorrow, but it shines light on the problem.

Comment: @mgilson: this is impressively annotated.

Comment: @mgilson:  Could you modify your example and call Foo from a method in Bar?

Comment: @Baf -- What do you mean?  It is "called" from a method on Bar (`__init__`)

Comment: @mglison: I see, sorry my mistake but could you do the same from inside the scope of Bar?

Comment: Also ive narrowed doen my problem. After i fixed the calling issues thanks to you guys posts, I now see what the real problem is. Im goin to post this in a new Question.

Answer (score 54):

So here is a simple example of how to use classes:
Suppose you are a finance institute. You want your customer's accounts to be managed by a computer. So you need to model those accounts. That is where classes come in. Working with classes is called object oriented programming. With classes you model real world objects in your computer. So, what do we need to model a simple bank account? We need a variable that saves the balance and one that saves the customers name. Additionally, some methods to in- and decrease the balance. That could look like:

```
class bankaccount():
    def __init__(self, name, money):
        self.name = name
        self.money = money

    def earn_money(self, amount):
        self.money += amount

    def withdraw_money(self, amount):
        self.money -= amount

    def show_balance(self):
        print self.money
```

Now you have an abstract model of a simple account and its mechanism.
The `def __init__(self, name, money)` is the classes' constructor. It builds up the object in memory. If you now want to open a new account you have to make an instance of your class. In order to do that, you have to call the constructor and pass the needed parameters. In Python a constructor is called by the classes's name:

```
spidermans_account = bankaccount("SpiderMan", 1000)
```

If Spiderman wants to buy M.J. a new ring he has to withdraw some money. He would call the `withdraw` method on his account:

```
spidermans_account.withdraw_money(100)
```

If he wants to see the balance he calls:

```
spidermans_account.show_balance()
```

The whole thing about classes is to model objects, their attributes and mechanisms. To create an object, instantiate it like in the example. Values are passed to classes with getter and setter methods like `earn_money()´. Those methods access your objects variables. If you want your class to store another object you have to define a variable for that object in the constructor.

Comment: Thx Man very illustrative! again I wisch i could accept this also as an answer, because it gave me some good insights, but mgilson answer is easier to transport to my acctual code. I wish all the python documentation was written like you guys doo it here, id spent less time on stackoverflow :P! Please dont lynch me now but I really think the python documentation is quite poor in terms of comprehensability! Thanks again MAxPowers this helped quite a bit!

Comment: @Baf -- just like anything else, give it some time.  Once you begin to learn the terminology of things, the python documentation is really very good.  In other words, just give yourself a little time to bump up over the learning curve and you'll grow to love the docs like the rest of us.

Comment: And +1 for an interesting example.

Comment: Great example, but it's still hard to think of how you would implement this in real life. You instantiate the object with a balance, but if you close Python, that balance for that account object is forgotten. It would be great to add some capabilities to store the balance in a text file and then get the balance from that text file every time an account object is created.

Answer (score 7):

The whole point of a class is that you create an *instance*, and that instance encapsulates a set of data. So it's wrong to say that your variables are global within the scope of the class: say rather that an instance holds attributes, and that instance can refer to its own attributes in any of its code (via `self.whatever`). Similarly, any other code given an instance can use that instance to access the instance's attributes - ie `instance.whatever`.