# Passing an instance of a class (object of a class) to another class

Tags: python, oop

What I do not understand is `b = Bar(a)`. What does it do? How is `Bar` taking `a` as an argument?

Won't that mean `Bar` inherits from `a`? What is `Bar.Foo1 = Foo`? Does it mean `Foo1` is an instance of class `Foo()`? How do we access `Foo1` when it itself is an object? What is the meaning of `b.arg.variable`? Doesn't it mean that `b` has a method `arg` which has a variable called `variable`? The following code is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11421962/3519372)

I just could not find parsing objects as an argument to another class.

```
  class Foo (object):
  #^class name  #^ inherits from object

      bar = "Bar" #Class attribute.

      def __init__(self):
          #        #^ The first variable is the class instance in methods.  
          #        #  This is called "self" by convention, but could be any name you want.
       

          self.variable="Foo" #instance attribute.
          print self.variable, self.bar  #<---self.bar references class attribute
          self.bar = " Bar is now Baz"   #<---self.bar is now an instance attribute
          print self.variable, self.bar  

       def method(self,arg1,arg2):
          #This method has arguments. You would call it like this : instance.method(1,2)
          print "in method (args):",arg1,arg2
          print "in method (attributes):", self.variable, self.bar


 a=Foo() # this calls __init__ (indirectly), output:
             # Foo bar
             # Foo  Bar is now Baz
 print a.variable # Foo
 a.variable="bar"
 a.method(1,2) # output:
               # in method (args): 1 2
               # in method (attributes): bar Bar is now Baz
 Foo.method(a,1,2) #<--- Same as a.method(1,2).  This makes it a little more explicit what the argument "self" actually is.

 class Bar(object):
     def __init__(self,arg):
          self.arg=arg
          self.Foo1=Foo()

 b=Bar(a)
 b.arg.variable="something"
 print a.variable # something
 print b.Foo1.variable # Foo
```

Comment: You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of Python.

Comment: I read that . There is no such thing as passing an object to another class. And I was unable to get from other sources

Comment: It is described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).  Everything is an object in Python.  Passing an object to a class is no different from passing an integer (as in that example), a string, or anything else.

Comment: Then b is an object of class Bar whose constructor will be called to initialize b, a`s(Foo()) or Bar()? and what is b.arg.variable?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  `a` was already created with the line `a = Foo()`, and Foo's `__init__` was called at that time.  When `Bar(a)` is executed, then Bar's `__init__` will be called.  The comments in your posted example seem to already mostly answer the questions you're asking.

Comment: Bar`s `__init__` would have been called even when it was `Bar(a)`.? What role does passing object `a` as an argument in `Bar()` play? Could you please explain `b.arg.variable`? is `arg` = `a` , like any other argument? Doesnt it make arg as an object ?

Comment: I don't understand what "Doesn't it make arg as an object" means.

Answer (score 14):

"What I do not understand is b = Bar(a). What does it do?"

`b = Bar(a)` does two things.  First, it creates an object of class `Bar` (with any class variables and methods attached).  Then, it runs `__init__` with the first argument (`self`) pointing to the object that was just created, and with `a` as the second argument (`arg`). While running `__init__`, as one of the commands in that method, it sets `self.arg` to point to the object pointed to by `arg` (i.e. to the object pointed to by the variable `a`). Finally, the variable `b` is set to refer to the object that was created.

It may help to think this way:  a variable in Python is really just a pointer that points to an object.  You can have more than one variable pointing to the same object.  In this case, `a` and `b.arg` both point to the same object.

I found this sort of thing confusing too, at first.  I had seen the advice to think of variables as separate concepts from the object they point to and ignored it as unnecessarily complicating things, but I had to go back to accepting that way of thinking in order to make sense of things.  People do often use the variable as a name to refer to the object it points to; you just have to know when to take this literally or not.

"Wont that mean Bar inherit from a?"

No.  If `a` is a class, then `class Bar(a)` would mean that Bar inherits from `a`.  But in 
`b = Bar(a)`, `a` is an object being passed as an argument to `__init__`.

"What is Bar.Foo1 = Foo?"

Sorry -- I don't see that in the example code you gave.

"What is the meaning of b.arg.variable?"

`b` is an object (i mean, `b` refers to an object) and `b.arg` is one of the attributes of that object. Methods and variables are different types of attributes.  In this case, `b.arg` is a variable pointing to an object.  The object referred to by `b.arg` has attribute `variable`, which is a variable.

`b.arg` refers to the same object that `a` refers to, therefore `b.arg.variable` is the same variable as `a.variable`.  It not only points to the same object, but actually is the same variable.  The object it points to is the string `"something"`.

@Brenbarn:  I think that's what quirius meant by "Wont that mean Bar inherit from a?".

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simpler example.  Suppose you have these classes:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
```

Here are two things you could do:

```
# Option 1: pass in an integer
>>> b = Bar(1)
>>> b.arg
1

# Option 2: pass in a Foo object
>>> a = Foo()
>>> b = Bar(a)
>>> b.arg
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000000002A440F0>
```

There is *no difference* in how the two cases are handled.  Passing in `a` (a Foo object) is no different from passing in an integer.  All that `Bar` does is store the value that is passed in, and it can store it just the same whether it is a Foo or an int.  When you call `Bar(something)`, it is entirely up to the `Bar` class how to handle the object that is passed in.  The type of the passed-in object is not involved except insofar as `Bar` chooses to explicitly involve it (e.g., by calling methods on the passed in object).

Comment: Thank you. and I apologize for asking trivial questions but I just could not get out of the java frame to think variable as a variable and not as an object.

Comment: @qurius: If I understand right, it now appears you were really asking about whether `Bar(a)` *creates* a new object that is somehow "based on" `a` (e.g., a copy of `a`).  Might have been good to mention that! :-)  When you just ask "what does Bar(a) do", it's not clear what about it you don't understand.

Comment: Yes , this indeed was what I meant to ask. :)

Comment: So is the `(object)` part in the class definition ever actually needed?