# How to pass information which button is clicked into another class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, parameter-passing, class-variables

I've searched and read, but don't quite understand other posts and/or it doesn't reflect problem I have.

I've tried different things from similar posts, like this one: [Passing variables, creating instances, self, The mechanics and usage of classes: need explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421659/passing-variables-creating-instances-self-the-mechanics-and-usage-of-classes), but apparantly, I don't understand classes, self quite enough (as can be seen I'm absolute beginner)

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, Frame, Label, StringVar, OptionMenu, Entry, Button, Toplevel
import pymysql as mdb
from functools import partial
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Home(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Control Panel")
        self.master.configure(background="#%02x%02x%02x" % (61, 72, 73))
        self.master.geometry("475x190")
        self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.main_frame = Frame(master, background="#%02x%02x%02x" % (61, 72, 73))
        self.main_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4, padx=15, pady=15)
        load1 = Image.open('plan.jpg')
        render1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load1)
        self.button_plan = Button(self.main_frame, image=render1, command=self.b_clicked('Planning'))
        self.button_plan.image = render1
        self.button_plan.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=12)
        self.label_plan = Label(self.main_frame, text='Planning', font='Calibri 9',
                            background="#%02x%02x%02x" % (61, 72, 73),
                            foreground="#%02x%02x%02x" % (255, 201, 14))
        self.label_plan.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=12)
        load2 = Image.open('consumption.jpg')
        render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load2)
        self.button_consumption = Button(self.main_frame, image=render2, command=self.b_clicked('Consumption'))
        self.button_consumption.image = render2
        self.button_consumption.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=12)
        self.label_consumption = Label(self.main_frame, text='Consumption', font='Calibri 9',
                                   background="#%02x%02x%02x" % (61, 72, 73),
                                   foreground="#%02x%02x%02x" % (255, 201, 14))
        self.label_consumption.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=12)


    def b_clicked(self, id):
        self.button_id = id
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.second_w = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Second(self.second_w, self.button_id)


class Second(object):
    def __init__(self, master, arg1):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Second")
        self.master.configure(background="#%02x%02x%02x" % (61, 72, 73))
        self.master.geometry("190x165")
        self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        print(arg1)

root = Tk()
GUI = Home(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to pass a variable value into another class. In this case I would like to get self.button_id value 'Planning'  from class Home to be passed to class Second. Point is... I don't need just solution. I would really like to understand it and this would be a great opportunity to learn it on my own example!

Comment: `Password(id)`?

Comment: Hey Ivan. Can you give us some more information about what this code is being used for? is 'master' inherited from a 3rd party module? Just trying to understand your project from a top level.

Comment: [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Goyo. Sorry, typing mistake

Comment: @Mathew, yes master is 3rd party.

Comment: Sorry, code is quite big, Ive paste just troubling part. And typing from phone as baby is awake so need to hold her

Comment: How is that you know how to pass `self.second_w ` but not `id `? It is the same.

Comment: @Goyo, as said, I'm absolute beginnee. I learn along the way as Im trying to make app and help myself and ease steps I have on my job (which is not IT related). I learned (and stll make mistakes) to pass and return values between functions but still not fully clear between classes

Comment: I dont quite understand

Comment: How does that make a difference between passing `self.second_w `and passing `id`or `self.button_id `?

Comment: Well that's a thing. If I would fully understand I would probably know how to do it.

Comment: Just pretend that `Second` is not a class but a function. "I would like to get `self.button_id` value `'Planning'` from class `Home` to be passed to function `Second`. You know how to do that, don't you?

Comment: I've tried something similar, but now with more success. Yes, it passed a value but instead of opening one "Second" window, it is opening 10 in same time. One for each function call and I expected function to be called upon button click.I forgot to mention (I didn't paste whole code). There is 10 buttons. Each with different value to pass to class Second! I modified code above to this new update!

Comment: Guess what `self.b_clicked('Planning') ` does.

Comment: :) I know that. Initial function was just b_clicked and it opened Second always on button click. But I needed information passed to next window Second about which button is pressed. They all should open Second but from there I should know which button led there. Now Home window is not even opened. It immediately execute b_clicked and not just once but for every button without even clicking on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

I reduced your code to get rid of all the code which is not problematic.

When you create the buttons, the `command` argument runs the callback function instead of just assigning it.

```
command=self.b_clicked('Planning')   # Will run self.b_clicked
```

Instead you can use a lambda expression in this assignment:

```
command=lambda:self.b_clicked('Planning')
```

In short: the function name is `self.b_clicked` and normally you would assign `command=self.b_clicked`, but as you want to pass an argument you will have to use **lambda** or **partial**, because ending a function name with parenthesis will just run the function.

As you create two buttons, your program immediately creates two new toplevel windows. When you reuse the name `self.second_w` for the second window you also lose the reference to the first toplevel window.

Also, you are using the name `id` for a variable which is not good as `id` is a builtin function.

Otherwise it seems to work just fine:

```
from tkinter import *

class Home():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.main_frame = Frame(master, bg='tan')
        self.main_frame.pack()

        self.button_plan = Button(self.main_frame, text='Plan', 
                                  command=lambda:self.b_clicked('Planning'))
        self.button_plan.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=12)

    def b_clicked(self, idty):      # "id" is a builtin function
        self.button_id = idty
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.second_w = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Second(self.second_w, self.button_id)

class Second():
    def __init__(self, master, arg1):
        self.master = master
        self.master.configure(bg='tomato')
        print(arg1)

root = Tk()
GUI = Home(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would like to thank @Goyo for pointing me in right direction and showing obvious.

Comment: and @figbeam for wrapping up solution. I have a clear picture now what was wrong!