# Is there a way to pass a variable to a class and create a class variable from it in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I was wondering if there was some way to pass a variable to a class, and set a class variable to that passed argument.
It would go something like this, but obviously it wouldn't work because it would be inheriting from variable:

```
def myClass(my_param):
    class_variable = my_param

    @classmethod
    def printVariable(cls):
        print(cls.class_variable)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is that supposed to say `class myClass`? And is `my_param` meant to be passed to `__init__`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variables, creating instances, self, The mechanics and usage of classes: need explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421659/passing-variables-creating-instances-self-the-mechanics-and-usage-of-classes)

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Please show an example of the usage you're trying to achieve. The snippet you posted doesn't make any sense, as @Carcigenicate pointed out. You can [edit] the question. Check out [ask] for tips if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguements through the `__init__` method of a class. Don't foget to set the first arguement to `self`. Also note calsses aren't defined like functions, you should use `class` instead of `def`.

EDIT
After quick googling it seems like your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421659/passing-variables-creating-instances-self-the-mechanics-and-usage-of-classes).

Comment: I'm not sure what OP's trying to do, but this doesn't sound like it. `__init__` doesn't normally set class attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Classes are first-class objects, and the execution of a `class` statement can make use of function parameters.

```
def make_class(value):
     class Foo:
         class_variable = value
         @classmethod
         def printVariable(cls):
             print(cls.class_variable)
     return Foo

Foo3 = make_class(3)
Foo3.printVariable()  # outputs 3
```

You can also call `type` directly.

```
def make_class(value):
    def printVariable(cls):
        print(cls.class_variable)

    return type('Foo', (), {'class_variable': value, 'printVariable': classmethod(printVariable)})
```

You also can do this without any function:

```
v = 3

class Foo:
    class_variable = v

    @classmethod
    def printVariable(cls):
        print(cls.class_variable)

v = 9

Foo.printVariable()  # outputs 3, not 9
```

When the `class` statement is executed, it uses the value of `v` at that time to initialize the class attribute `class_variable`; it does not save the name `v` and wait until you want to see the value of `class_variable` before looking up `v`.