# Can I use a variable with a class attribute / function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It doesn't allow me to use a variable with an attribute of the class. Not sure how to manage this.
I need the answer to come out as 7. But I need to be able to use the variable for it. gives me the error,

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Data/First Game (Python)/rough.py", line 32, in 
a.add_2(5)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'x'

I think it is not able to recognize that by a I meant to mention Me1.

```
class Test():
    def add_2(self, y):
        print(y + 2)

Me1 = Test()

for i in range (1):
    a = "Me" + str(i+1)
    print (a)
    a.add_2(5)
```

Comment: `a is string object` and `Me1 is a class object`, you can't do like this. Please specify what you want to acheive.

Comment: `a = eval("Me" + str(i + 1))` should work, but why are you doing this? this approach makes no sense.

Comment: Dive into class objects: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Comment: If you `Me1.add_2(5)` you will print `7` , is this the expected result?

Comment: There is nothing in your question that explains why you need to loop, or need to dynamically make a string that corresponds to a variable name... etc. If you want to refer to `Me1`, why not just do so? Why loop at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variables, creating instances, self, The mechanics and usage of classes: need explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421659/passing-variables-creating-instances-self-the-mechanics-and-usage-of-classes)

Comment: Understood. the eval function seems to work great. This is a simplified version of a loop that I was trying to create in pygame but it wasn't working due to the string and class mismatch earlier. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense on constructing an object of a class at runtime unless you're exploring something to learn. But, here is what you're looking for,

```
class Test():
    def add_2(self, y):
        print(y + 2)

Me1 = Test()

for i in range (1):
    a = "Me" + str(i+1)
    print(a)
    b = eval(a) # converting str to Class Test object
    b.add_2(5)
```

**Output:**

```
Me1
7
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: Thank you, yes, it's for learning purposes only.Quite a beginner at this so was not sure what the error was.

Comment: Cool, Kindly accept the answer if it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the variable `a` is a string while the function `a.add_2(5)` belongs to the objects of class `Test`. The error is caused by the fact that you call a method of class `Test`on a string